# excelExporter illegal navigation seam

Tags: seam

I have a Rich:dataTable and I want to export it with excelExporter seam component. It works ok for pages that does not have a pageflow defined. But when I have a pageFlow(jpdl) than I get Illegal Navigation. I suppose that this happens because the exporter does a redirect for the user to be able to download the excel file. 
How can I define a rule or something to allow the exporter to make the redirect so that the file will be downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `ExcelExporter` is that it is too tightly coupled with the document store, it will always generate a redirect to the document store to fetch the generated file. There are no workarounds to this. Same goes for PDF generation.

So you need to account for that redirect in the pageflow, but even if you do, you would also need to account for the navigation away from the document store after the excel is downloaded, otherwise the pageflow would reposition you back to the document store (triggering the download again and again). A trick for doing so is described in https://community.jboss.org/thread/185716 (basically you create a bogus value expression that repositions the pageflow in the previous page once you render the excel worksheet).

Possible workarounds:

1. perform the download in a separate popup window or in an `<iframe/>` within a valid pageflow page
2. export the excel worksheet via javascript/flash

Comment: I've written my own ExcelExporter actually pasted the code from the original one and instead of using DocumentStore I've used my own DownloadBean.